# Get just a column from a relationship, Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

Get `pluck('name');` from a Controller. Right now I get all data from relationship (id,created_at, etc).

```
//from my User Controller
$user = User::where('id', $id)->get(['id', 'name', 'email', 'points'])->first();
$user->abilities();

//from my User Model
    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class)->withTimestamps();
    }
    public function abilities()
    {
        return $this->roles->map->abilities->flatten()->pluck('name')->unique(); //from here I want to get just the name
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the return value of your `map` and instead use `flatMap` and remove use of `flatten`.

```php
public function abilities()
{
    $abilities = $this->roles->flatMap->abilities;
    return $abilities->pluck('name')->unique(); 
}
```

**Reference**

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-flatmap

> The `flatMap` method iterates through the collection and passes each value to the given callback. The callback is free to modify the item and return it, thus forming a new collection of modified items. Then, the array is flattened by a level:

Comment: @Beuseblu sorry that doesn't make sense and neither does your original question. You need to add to your answer your full controller code function, and relevant parts of user model and roles model. It seems like you are not actually using the`abilities` function from the `User` model. The `pluck` would return an empty array if it could not find the `name` field.

Answer (score 0):

```
 // use pluck in controller
   $user->abilities()->pluck('name');
 // model
  public function abilities()
     {
     return $this->hasMany(AvailabilityModelName::class, 'id');
      }
```